# In the US, are there any areas of governance which are not under control of the Federal Government?

Tags: united-states

While the US Constitution originally reserved a lot of powers to the States, in recent decades the Congress and the Federal Government have been able to maintain control over much wider areas of public governance. For example, the alcohol prohibition required a constitutional amendment while the prohibition on recreational drugs was passed as a simple law thanks to a more liberal interpretation of the Commerce clause. Likewise the Federal government has managed to push through reforms such as a higher drinking age by threatening to take away funding from states which fail to follow in line.

As of present day, are there still any areas of public governance which are under the exclusive control of the States themselves?

Comment: Recommend assert and maintain over simple assert. For the later examples, consider that the cudgel of withholding federal funding speaks more to the reliance the state has on redistributed wealth.

Comment: Are you interested in functions that have state programs without federal involvement or only programs that also have no comparable federal program? Or are you talking about some activity I could do that is regulated by my state and the feds have no rules about it and do not attempt to influence the state government? (with the assumption that driving on roads to do it or having learned to read in a school meeting standards outlined by the feds doesn't poison the whole well)

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt I'm looking for activities that are regulated by the state government and which were attempted to be regulated by the federal government but failed for various reasons (constitutional limits, supreme court judgement, lack of means of enforcement, etc). If South Carolina regulates rope skipping for some reason it wouldn't count since the federal government never attempted to regulate it.

Comment: A fair amount of the rhetoric coming from the deregulation wing of the Republican party currently seems to support the feds backing off of various projects. Would any success of states' rights be acceptable? With say marijuana, some states have won at least temporary control for one part of drug enforcement, but other parts of the same act are uncontested and it isn't totally settled.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt marijuana laws enforcement has been a deliberate decision by the federal government, rather than something forced upon them by the Supreme Court. I'm interested in areas where DC tried to intervene, the states declined their intervention, and they've subsequently dropped the idea altogether or were rejected by the Supreme Court.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt the only things I can think of are: assigning members of the Electoral College and the organization of elections in general (although I'm not sure if there isn't a federal standard all states must follow).

Comment: Such a scary question, everything I think of the Fed has their nose in it, Schools: fed funding, taxation(income and sales): fed regulation, welfare: fed welfare ceiling, Colleges: fed funding. Maybe hunting and fishing?

Comment: @FrankCedeno yeah, which is why I am a bit perplexed about the whole concept of "states rights". What are those rights exactly?

Comment: @JonathanReez There is a ton of debate about what exactly states rights are. Arguably its the fundamental divider between conservatives and liberals in the US. Technically speaking its defined by the [10th amendment](https://www.google.com/search?q=10th+amendment&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS750US750&oq=10th+am&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.1343j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), but interpretations of the 10th vary wildly.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg, the debate is about how states rights have been eroded. From that point of view, States rights are the individual bargain the specific state has struck with the fed. The example marijuana: California: medicinal, Oregon: Recreational. A more recent debate: should the fed dictate genderless bathrooms for all or should each state make their own rules on the subject. I assumed the OP question was about rights where the Fed has none, in real life, the Fed has varying degrees of controls

Comment: @FrankCedeno Like I said, interpretations vary wildly :).

Comment: The examples in the question don't really back up the implication (though the answer given is a nice rebuttal). As for "states rights"...that's just pundit-speak that got really popular when certain groups decided they didn't like having to treat gay people equally.

Comment: JonathanReez: Perhaps you ought to include the clarifications in the question as the existing answer (posted after your second clarification) doesn't seem to address them. @blip The civil war had states' rights arguments and I understand the less overtly racist anti-civil rights speeches even used similar words.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt yea, it's a phrase that has come and gone throughout history. But usually it means the same thing: someone is upset about equal rights.

Answer (score 5):

Tons. Arguably even most of governance is not done at the federal level. This is why every city and state has its own governance and pass their own laws and ordinances. I'll enumerate a small and by no means exhaustive list:

## Municipal Governance

Things like garbage collection, parking tickets, zoning, tourism boards, etc are all almost exclusively handled at the municipal level. Its possible that the municipal governments may receive aid and funding from the federal level that may come with some restrictions, but the final decisions rest solely in the hands of the municipality.

## Law Enforcement

Police departments will be funded by the local government, but the laws they enforce will mainly be state laws. Take for example murder. Unless you cross state lines that will be handled entirely in state.

## Drinking age

This actually *is* handled by the states. They have full discretion over the drinking age. Now they have all decided to make the drinking age 21 because they don't want to [lose 10% of their highway funding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Minimum_Drinking_Age_Act), but they are not forced to do so. Any state can lower their drinking age tomorrow. In fact, even after the Drinking Age Act was passed some states held their drinking age at a lower number (Louisiana held out at effectively 18 until 1995, 11 years after the act passed).

## State Constitutions

States can define their own constitutions that really don't need to look anything like the US constitution (with one exception being that [they must be a republic](https://www.usconstitution.net/xconst_A4Sec4.html)). The federal government does not control what goes into a state constitution.

Comment: A suggestion/correction: the federal executive and legislature don't define what can and can't go into a state's constitution, but the US Constitution (and its interpretation by the courts) does, e.g. the application of parts of the Bill of Rights to the states, and the Constitution's guarantee that all states have a republican form of government.

Comment: @owjburnham That is true of all things though. Even parking laws have to abide by the US Constitution. Also I'm not sure that the constitution guarantees that all states have a republican form of government, can you cite where that is stipulated?

Comment: I would have referenced, but was commenting from my phone, sorry. It appears to be [Article 4, Section 4](https://www.usconstitution.net/xconst_A4Sec4.html): "The United States shall guarantee to every State in this Union a Republican Form of Government, and shall protect each of them against Invasion; and on Application of the Legislature, or of the Executive (when the Legislature cannot be convened) against domestic Violence."

Comment: @owjburnham Thanks for pointing that, you learn something new every day :). Ill update my answer

Comment: Good answer, but the state Constitution is just a document. What matters is the practical side of things.

Comment: As for state crimes - as far as I understand you can commit a federal crime without crossing a state border if Congress deems your particular action a federal crime (e.g. hacking)

Comment: @JonathanReez "state Constitution is just a document" Really all of laws are just pieces of paper, even the US Constitution. But we all put faith in them, so its really not "just a document", its really something that carry weight practically.

Comment: @JonathanReez First off Congress doesn't decide who to prosecute, that is up to the executive branch (via groups like the FBI and AG). Second off they can't just 'decide' something is federal. They are bound by legislation. Now there is already some legislation that may say 'hacking is a federal crime', but they all need to stand up to judicial review (otherwise a state can sue to prevent the feds from prosecuting). In general to show its a federal offense you need to show that the crime crosses state lines (easily demonstrated with hacking because the internet crosses state lines).

Comment: There are tens of thousands of Federal law enforcement agents and all state and local law enforcement must submit to them.

Comment: @Hack-R That is factually incorrect. The meter maid does not need to submit to an FBI agent. The FBI has no jurisdiction over parking infractions. The same is true for some local murder charge. Unless there is a reason to make it federal they can't make the police 'submit'.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg That's absolutely incorrect. While a judge can later rule that an action or command given to a meter maid or police officer was was illegal or otherwise invalid post hoc, local law enforcement are absolutely required to defer to orders from Federal law enforcement when given, in every case.

Comment: @Hack-R Please provide citations for your assertion, because I can show you several cases where you are wrong (ie see recent directives from State governments to not cooperate with ICE[key word being cooperate, so even before it wasn't submit, it was just cooperation])

Comment: @DavidGrinberg " Unless you cross state lines that will be handled entirely in state." is not strictly true. For example, in my state there was a high-profile kidnapping/murder case last year where the FBI was involved. The main justification for FBI involvement in that case was not that there was travel between states, but that the suspect used a car to transport the victim which could be used for travel across state lines. So, it's not explicitly necessary for inter-state activity to have occurred, but in this case, for there to have been a reasonable possibility or means for it.

Answer (score 0):

Recent not fully settled examples include [sanctuary cities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanctuary_city),  [marijuana legalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannabis_in_the_United_States) and [health care](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patient_Protection_and_Affordable_Care_Act#Non-cooperation).

In these cases states are openly defying federal rules. These are ongoing issues, and there is at least talk of the federal government asserting authority but so far there has been limited action and nothing effective. The current administration has taken a stance less favorable to the first two examples than the previous administration and more favorable to the third.

Previous issues where states have clearly won include [assisted suicide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_suicide_in_the_United_States#Challenges) and some kinds of discrimination like [age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimel_v._Florida_Board_of_Regents#Opinion_of_the_Court) and [disability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_of_Trustees_of_the_University_of_Alabama_v._Garrett#Result).